# NGINX proxy_pass same protocol (http/https)

Tags: nginx

I have a section in my NGINX config file that uses `proxy_pass` to redirect API traffic to upstream servers. I have the `location`s in one `server` block that serves both http and https requests:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name mysite.local;    # Valid TLD in production
```

I then have `location` blocks to define my API gateways:

```
    location /api/v1/json {
        # Various proxy config directives
        proxy_pass http://upstream;
```

My question is: would it be possible to drop `http://` and pass requests to my upstream servers depending on the protocol without splitting my `server` block? Something like HTML/JavaScript `//mysite.local` requests.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use the `$scheme` variable:

```
location /api/v1/json {
    # Various proxy config directives
    proxy_pass $scheme://your-host
}
```

From the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html):

```
$scheme
request scheme, "http" or "https"
```

Which would then use the same protocol as the original request.

Comment: I agree. This prevent hair-pulling incidents whilst copy-pasting configs around between location blocks. You don't want an `http` ending up in an `https` server location block, or vice versa.