Why is this NGINX proxy_pass scheme not working
I have an nginx server running and am doing a reverse proxy to other web systems. below is my configuration
server {
    # HTTP configuration
    
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;       
    server_name example.com;
    
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.log  info;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.log  main;

    ssl_certificate root/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key root/privkey.pem;


location / {       
    proxy_redirect        off;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;
     proxy_read_timeout 3600;
     resolver_timeout 60s;
    
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    proxy_pass $scheme://192.168.1.1/;
  }
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   } 
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; 
 }

i can't tell why when i open the page it does work but when i change the proxy_pass $scheme://192.168.1.1/ to proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/ it works perfectly.
the goal is, i want to be able to access both http and https for that particular system

$schema should work (according to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46516250/724039 )   Maybe add some logging?: How do you log proxy_pass in the nginx access log?  (or, in other words, it is unclear which error(s) you are getting when "it does not work".

The main difference with using variables in proxy_pass is the need to add a resolver.

@luuk Per my directives i pick all my logs via these
error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.log  info;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.log  main;
Is there another way to go about it?

@RichardSmith how can i add a resolver

@Luuk i get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS from my browser. In my error log i get *14 client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while waiting for request, client: 80.87.95.194, server: 0.0.0.0:443

@AugustusBuckman follow the link in my comment or go here.

@RichardSmith i have my resolver set in my directives via IPv4
